# React Native Form request

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, request, fetch

I am trying to send simple **POST Forms React Native Fetch request** from an Android Emulator to the **NodeJS server**. The NodeJS server does not detect this, (it works by using Postman api). Please help me :)

Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var accs = [];

var server = app.listen(8082, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log("here");
  let login = req.query.login;
  let password = req.query.password;
  accs.push({login: hashCode(login), password: hashCode(password)})
  console.log(login + " " + password);
  res.send("Created: L:" + hashCode(login) + " P:" + hashCode(password));
})
```

React Native Fetch:

```
  registerAcc() {
    var details = {
    'login': 'Login',
    'password': 'Password!',
  };

  var formBody = [];
  for (var property in details) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");

  fetch('http://localhost:8082/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },
      body: formBody
    }).then((response) => {
      this.setState({msg : "1"})
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({msg : '2'});
    });
  }
```

The emulator also show a communicate:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Resection (id: 0): Network request
>   failed...

But the catch function is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use "localhost" in Android Emulator, refers to mobile and not in your computer.

You can replace localhost by "10.0.2.2" in the app, this is a alias to host of android emulator, that in the case, your computer.

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses

Or

Get the network address, and you can run on your mobile too (if in same network). In windows, use the command **ipconfig** in your CMD to get network IPv4 address.